# UIScrollView slideShow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

```
UIScrollView *scrl  = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768,1024)];
scrl.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 8, 1024);
```

Here is the definition of my `UIScrollView`, I have a fill the scroll with 8 images each image is a **768*1024**, how can I make `UIScrollView` slide show, each image stay 2 seconds and slides to the next image, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an UIImageView instead of a UIScrollView.

In your .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    int imageId;
    UIImageView *imageView;    
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView;

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
@implementation ViewController

#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>


#define NUMBER_OF_IMAGES 8;

@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageId = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeImage
{
    imageId = imageId + 1;

    CATransition * trs = [CATransition animation];
    trs.duration = 1;
    [trs setType:kCATransitionPush];

    int id = imageId % NUMBER_OF_IMAGES;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.jpg", id]];
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:trs forKey:kCATransition];
}

@end
```

You will need to add the QuartzCore.framework to your project.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, but what does this line `int id = imageId % NUMBER_OF_IMAGES;` does exactly?  I'm specifically confused about the `% NUMBER_OF_IMAGES` bit. Does it place a limit on the value that `id` can be set to (in this case, 8)? Because I would otherwise use an if-statement to check if `id` is already 8... did not know about that type of notation you used.

Comment: @miamk % operator compute the remainder of dividing imageId by NUMBER_OF_IMAGES. Then with this operation id value is always between 0 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you any code (that's YOUR job)...

Here is how to do such a thing:

Have a parent UIScrollView that handles paging - must implement the delegate method of scrollViewDidScroll:

Have a UIPageControl (used for keeping track of what page you are on, code-wise or UI wise)

IMPORTANT for zooming: 
1. Create a subclass of UIScrollView and add a UIImageView to it as a subview. 
2. Allow scrolling and no paging. 
3. Make this subclass have implement the delegate method of viewForZoomingInScrollView: (return the UIImageView)